# How to pass value on onclick function in laravel

Tags: javascript, laravel, laravel-5

I want to send a value to a javascript function when a button is clicked. The value comes from the database. How can I do it using laravel blade?

Here is my HTML code:

```
<a  href="" onclick="add($res->driver_id);"><i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o"></i></a>
```

and my javascript:

```
<script>
function add(var id)
{
    alert(id);
}
</script>
```

Comment: Your function doesn't need "var", like this function add(id) { alert(id); }

Comment: If the value comes from the DB you should pass it to the view from your controller.

Comment: okey i am changed it.! but it not alert value that i am passed

Comment: ya the value come from db it was retrieved from controller to view.I want show that value as alert when button is click!!

Answer (score 6):

Just use double curly brackets

```
<a  href="" onclick="add( {{ $res->driver_id }} );"><i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o"></i></a>
```

Keep in mind that when blade template renders, it replaces variavles with its values
For example if `$res->driver_id = "randomstring"`, then after blade rendering you'll got this HTML:

```
<a  href="" onclick="add(randomstring);"><i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o"></i></a>
```

So if you need to pass string to your add function, you need wrap argument that you passed with quotes, like so:

```
<a  href="" onclick="add('{{ $res->driver_id }}');"><i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o"></i></a>
```

Comment: you are correct but it not alert any value it was reload when click the button

Comment: i made a mistake it will work fine..!! thanks for your help..!!

Answer (score 2):

You have write PHP code in HTML page so it will pass as it is, You have to take it in PHP and if you got the driver_id value in your views file then you can pass it to easily to the javascript function like following code.

PHP Code :-

```
<a  href="" onclick="add({{$res->driver_id}});"><i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o"></i></a>
```

Javascript code :-

```
<script>
function add(id)
{
    alert(id);
}
</script>
```

It may help you.

Answer (score 2):

if you want to sent a parameters just need to add the '{{ }}' and without ; in the call method for example:

```
<button onclick= "request('{{$data-> id}}','{{$data-> name}}', '{{$data-> description}}')"> Solicitar Cita</button>
```

Here i send 3 parameters. In your case just add the apostrophes:

```
<a  href="" onclick="add('{{$res->driver_id}}')"><i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o"></i></a>
```